# Is there a way to require function parameter to be a constructor of type parameter?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to write this:

```
foo<T>(bar: ConstructorOf<T>): T
```

so this code would be legal:

```
class Baz {}

foo(Baz); // type param T infered to be Baz
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
class Baz {
  isBaz = true;
}

function foo<T>(c : {new(): T;}): T {
  return new c;
}

console.log(foo(Baz).isBaz); // ok
console.log(foo(String).length); // ok
// console.log(foo(String).isBaz); // error: property isBaz does not exist in type String
```

This code is a simplified example from the last topic in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.